# Matlab is English version, but when plot figure I got Chinese

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

[image]

As you can see from the picture, it's wired to have Chinese. I only need the year, 2012, 2013, 2014... to be displayed.

I have checked the DateReturn, which is:
[image]

Others may have the same problem like me, so I post it here.

Comment: Please post your code, it is not possible to tell you what you’re doing wrong if you don’t show what you’re doing. We need to be able to reproduce your issue, os include enough code for that. Copy-paste the code into the question, don’t post images of code. See [mcve].

Comment: Thank you for your notice and help! I have solved this problem, it is not related to the code. After I changed my system time setting from Chinese to English, this problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Even I have changed the Matlab version from Chinese to Englsih, but I still need to change the computer system version from Chinese to English. After doing this further step, the display will be English.